# Need some help with nodal analysis

Tags: nodal-analysis

I have this circuit where I'm supposed to find the current I. I know I'll find it by (V3-V4)/R10. I have done the nodal analysis, however, my teacher says that I have done my nodal analysis incorrectly, but I can't figure out what the problem is. I already have all the values for the resistors, current source, and voltage source, and the resistor between V5 and V4 is called R7, I just forgot to label it.
Maybe someone has an idea of what I have missed in the nodal analysis.

[image]

Comment: Your diagram is pretty small and a bit messy. I think you may have mixed up V5 and V6 on occasion. Also, why do you have V1 and V6 at all?

Comment: Echoing Elliots comment, V6 and V1 are 0.  It's where you have put your ground reference. So try again with that simplification.

Comment: Yes, I know, well when I did my calculations I assumed that V6= 0 and V1=0 already and it's still an issue. I had added V1 and V6 just for clarification for the nodal analysis, even though it doesn't have any impact.

Comment: Wait, I think I found the issue actually, on V2 I have (V2-V6)/R4, which is not possiable